# Is there a more efficient and less ugly way to load variable-length data into a nested data structure in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, nested

I have a number of HDF5 files which are saved in a hierarchical manner (i.e. multiple folders containing multiple files where the files in each folder are related - I am not referring to the hierarchical structure of individual HDF5 files). I want to read the data (a vector) from each file and store it in a data structure which reflects the hierarchical between the files. However, the length of the data varies between files. In the example below the data is stored in a field of the HDF5 file called "data".

If the data from each file was the same length, I would simply use a NumPy array. However, because of the variable lengths I have been using nested lists as follows:

```
import glob
import h5py 

# list of directories
dir_list = ["dir1", "dir2"]

# load data and store in nested list
data = []
for dir_idx, dir in enumerate(dir_list):
    data.append([])
    file_list = glob.glob(dir + "/*.hdf5")
    for file_idx, file in enumerate(file_list):
        with h5py.File(file, "r") as fid:
            data[dir_idx].append(fid["data"][:])
```

This seems inefficient and looks ugly, but I don't know a better solution. Ideally, I would like to use NumPy because of the more efficient memory management. Could anybody suggest a more elegant solution?

Comment: Skip the [] append and do `data.append(fid["data"][:])`.  I think  that does the same thing.  You are just collecting the `data` from each file in a list.  Nothing wrong with that for mixed sizes.  It's the file read that's the main time consumer, not the list storage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hpaulj. I see that removing the `data.append([])` would achieve the same thing in this case, but if I were to add a third layer of nesting then I would need to add it in the outside for loop, so it wouldn't really solve the problem. I take the point about the file reading being the main performance-limiting factor, though. I guess it just looks a bit ugly but if there isn't an obviously better way performance-wise then I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner way of building a nested list of arrays is:

```
data = []
for dir in dir_list:
    data1 = []
    file_list = glob.glob(dir + "/*.hdf5")
    for file in file_list:
        with h5py.File(file, "r") as fid:
            data1.append(fid["data"][:])
    data.append(data1)
```

It should do the same thing, just without the `enumerate` and `idx`.  No difference in performance.  It's loading the same "data" dataset from each file in each dir.

I was going to say you make a 2d or higher array to store the datasets, but that's only possible if `len(file_list)` is the same for all `dir`, and you know that ahead of time.  And if all "data" datasets are the same shape, you could start with something like a

```
 arr = np.zeros((len(dir_list), len(file_list), N, M), float)
```

Then the enumerate would useful in assign values to

```
 arr[dir_index, file_index,:, : ] = fit['data'][:]
```

One way or other you have to iterate on the dirs and files.  As long as you don't use things like `np.append` in the loops, it doesn't matter a whole lot how you collect the arrays.

Comment: Good suggestion - this is more readable, thank you!